# Drawing 6 graphs from a text file in CERN ROOT

Tags: c++, c, root-framework

I am new in ROOT.
I have a text file contains 9 columns and 96 rows.
I want to read the 1st, 4th and 5th columns and store the values in x,y,ey.

I would like to plot 6 graphs, one for each different value of the third column of the original text file.

For example the rows 1,4,7 etc have the same value in 3rd column (in my case -0.7):

`{x=(row=1column=1,row=7column=1,row=13column=1, row=19column=1.......)}`,
`{y=(row=1column=4,row=7column=4,row=13column=4, row=19column=4.....)}` and    `{ey=(row=1column=5,row=7column=5,row=13column=5, row=19column=5.....)}`

(Here below a picture is attached to show the data).

[image: Data]

Please let me know how to do it.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: can you rephrase what you want to plot? I don't understand from what you wrote. E.g. you speak about entries that have the value in the third column, but, same as what? Do you want to select those rows where the value in the third column is the same **as in the 1st column**? Do you want to draw only for rows that have a specific value in the third column? Do you want to group the rows by unique values in the third column, and create a graph for each unique value in the third column?

Comment: sorry for my pouring English, yes I want to group the rows by unique values in the third column, and create a graph for each unique value in the third column

Answer (score 2):

There are a few sub-steps of your task, for each of which you have probably several options.

1. read the csv

[stackoverflow has you covered here for standalone c++](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+read+csv) which you then can work with in standard c++ or using root tools, and [for reading into a ttree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474991/how-to-create-root-histograms-out-of-a-3-column-dat-file/43195208#43195208), or [using regular data science tools with root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420191/converting-900-mb-csv-into-root-cern-ttree) or [with a root tgraph constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475239/plotting-ascii-files-in-root/44531699#44531699) (but i'm not familiar with the tgraph object family for more than reading the docs).

2. selecting third column values

I'm most familiar with the TTree, here you could go for something along the lines of (depends how you actually create the tree) `your_tree->Draw("fourth_column_for_y_axis:first_column_for_x_axis","third_column==-0.7")`

There are problems here: you need to still find out the third column values to select and build the selection string (second argument of `TTree::Draw`).
(and others for the next points), so I suggest to keep the third column values actually in some c++ data structure. Filling them in a `unique_set` should pretty much do what you need.

3. Plotting

Here I actually think `TTree::Draw` turns out a bad solution (with two variable drawing `y:x` you actually make a two-dimensional histogram, while a two-dimensional graph is rather a representation of a one-dimensional histogram, which you can trick by filling with weights `TTree::Draw("first_column",Form("(third_column==%f)*fourth_column",-0.7))`, but then you'd still need to get the error bars right, and the math for that would probably be more hack than solution and unmaintainable).

4. find out a combination of tools that suits you

So I think it makes more sense to load the data with any of the standard c++ from above into STL containers and use STL algorithms to juggle your data. Once you have it in some shape you can get the graphs (no points for good code here, just sketching how to construct the `TGraphErrors` with untested quasi code that I hope is easy enough to read with little prerequistis):

```
std::unique_set<float> third_column_unique_values = …
std::vector<std::tuple<float,float,float,float> > rows_1_3_4_5 = …

// loop over all unique values in the third column
for (auto third_value : third_column_unique_values) {
  std::vector<float> x, y, ey;
  // now loop over all rows and skip the "currently wrong ones"
  for (auto row: rows_1_3_4_5) {
    // WARNING: indices of rows and tuples get confusing
    // WARNING: float point comparison here, that's bad
    if (std::get<1>(row) != third_value) continue;

    x.push_back(std::get<0>(row));
    y.push_back(std::get<2>(row));
    ey.push_back(std::get<3>(row));
  }

  /// I didn't find a TGraphError class with only errors in y direction,
  // but only searched for a few seconds, you might go more into
  // detail, I just set them all to 0 here

  std::vector<float> ex(0.f, x.size());
  TGraphErrors* graph = new TGraphErrors(x.size(), &x[0], &y[0], &ex[0], &ey[0]);
}
```

And then you probably want to get the `graph` out of the loop. NB: No need to worry about pointing to the beginnings of the `x`, `y`, … vectors, the constructor of `TGraphErrors` copies the contents of the expected arrays.